# R RSI Calculation (TTR package)

Tags: r, indicator, moving-average

I'm using the *default* RSI calculation in the TTR package as follows:

result = RSI(data,14).

The function also allows the user to specify the averaging method:

result = RSI(data,14,"SMA"), 
result = RSI(data,14, "EMA") etc.

However, I cannot work out what averaging method is being used in the *default* version. I have compared the results from all the different averaging methods (SMA, EMA) and none of them match the default. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the default uses the Wilder EMA, which does act slightly different from a standard EMA.

i.e. Default = RSI(data,14,"EMA",wilder = TRUE)

For more information on the Wilder Moving Average - https://www.incrediblecharts.com/indicators/wilder_moving_average.php

Comment: Can the user set the default to "EMA" and to not use wilder, without adjust the function code ? I get a discrepancy between 2 system that has the same OHLC-data source. the discrepancy is in the RSI result and I suspect it might have to do with that one system uses the TTR (thus wilder setting) and the other system does not use TTR (wilder).

Comment: I noticed that I get different results, adding the wilder flag, with or without [maType="EMA". That seems a bug, since not typing [maType="EMA] should give the "EMA" as default.

Answer (score 1):

The TTR RSI code uses EMA by default. Code below:

https://github.com/joshuaulrich/TTR/blob/master/R/RSI.R

```
# Default Welles Wilder EMA
if(missing(maType)) {
    maType <- 'EMA'
    maArgs$wilder <- TRUE
}
```